# Crystal Fiber error - "Unhandled exception in spawn: SSL_shutdown: Operation now in progress (Errno)"

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm new to crystal and am trying to spawn fibers to check whether a status is complete or not. Here is some code.

```
def fiber_operations()
    status = -1

    spawn do
       while status != 5
           response = HTTP::Client.get "https://api.com/endpoint"
           response_to_hash = JSON.parse response.body
           status = response_to_hash["status"]
           sleep 2.seconds
       end
    end

    Fiber.yield
end
```

When I create a few of these this error occurs (it seems to be running fine before this):

> "Unhandled exception in spawn: SSL_shutdown: Operation now in progress
>   (Errno)"

EDIT:

Added more information, I thought a toy example may be good enough but it may be related to HTTP::Client so I added it in. I am doing a GET for some api endpoint and get the status that way. Maybe if one GET is in progress another cannot be opened? If so, how to do this?

EDIT 2:

Was not a fix.

Answer (score 1):

You may have hit [crystal-lang/crystal#3168](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/3168).

I've written this program for testing, and it seems to work:

```
require "http/client"
require "json"

status = -1

spawn do
  while status != 5
    puts "Pinging..."
    response = HTTP::Client.get "https://randomapi.com/api/6de6abfedb24f889e0b5f675edc50deb?fmt=raw&sole"
    puts "Pong"
    response_to_hash = JSON.parse response.body
    status = response_to_hash[0]["first"].to_s.size
    pp status
  end
  puts "Finish!"
  exit 0
end

Fiber.yield

puts "Post yield"

sleep 20000.seconds # so the main thread doesn't exit yet
```

I don't think this has much to do with the fibers, but with that Crystal/OpenSSL bug. Maybe you can `rescue` the exception inside the `spawn` block to see the actual exception.

Comment: Have you tried spawning a lot of these at once? I only seem to see the issue when I have 5 or more running. Also, could you explain what the error message means?

Comment: I'm not sure what the error means. I could reproduce the issue by spawning multiple fibers, and added this info to [the bug's report](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/3168#issuecomment-261438279), so maybe the team can work it out soon.

Comment: Thanks for adding it to the bug's report. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This "error" related to waitlistt  for operation completed. Should be fixed by https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/pull/4433

And now released with Crystal 0.23.0